# React FC Context & Provider Typescript Value Issues

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

Trying to implement a global context on an application which seems to require that a value is passed in, the intention is that an API will return a list of organisations to the context that can be used for display and subsequent API calls.

When trying to add the `<Provider>` to App.tsx the application complains that value hasn't been defined, whereas I'm mocking an API response with `useEffect()`.

Code as follows:

**Types `types/Organisations.ts`**

```
export type IOrganisationContextType = {
  organisations: IOrganisationContext[] | undefined;
};

export type IOrganisationContext = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
};

export type ChildrenProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};
```

**Context `contexts/OrganisationContext.tsx`**

```
export const OrganisationContext = React.createContext<
  IOrganisationContextType
>({} as IOrganisationContextType);

export const OrganisationProvider = ({ children }: ChildrenProps) => {
  const [organisations, setOrganisations] = React.useState<
    IOrganisationContext[]
  >([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setOrganisations([
      { id: "1", name: "google" },
      { id: "2", name: "stackoverflow" }
    ]);
  }, [organisations]);

  return (
    <OrganisationContext.Provider value={{ organisations }}>
      {children}
    </OrganisationContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Usage `App.tsx`**

```
const { organisations } = React.useContext(OrganisationContext);
  return (
    <OrganisationContext.Provider>
      {organisations.map(organisation => {
        return <li key={organisation.id}>{organisation.name}</li>;
      })}
    </OrganisationContext.Provider>
  );
```

**Issue #1:**

```
Property 'value' is missing in type '{ children: Element[]; }' but required in type 'ProviderProps<IOrganisationContextType>'.
```

**Issue #2:**

The list is not rendering on `App.tsx`

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-dream-07wtn?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different things that you'll need to look out for in this:

1. If I'm reading the intention of the code properly, you want to render `OrganisationProvider` in `App.tsx` instead of OrganisationContext.Provider. `OrganisationProvider` is the custom wrapper you have for setting the fake data.
2. Once this is fixed, you're going to run into an infinite render loop because in the `OrganisationProvider` component, the `useEffect` sets the `organisations` value, and then runs whenever `organisations` changes. You can probably set this to an empty array value `[]` so the data is only set once on initial render.
3. You're trying to use the context before the provider is in the tree above it. You'll need to re-structure it so that the content provider is always above any components trying to consume context. You can also consider using the context consumer component so you don't need to create another component.

With these suggested updates, your `App.tsx` could look something like the following:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import {
  OrganisationContext,
  OrganisationProvider
} from "./contexts/OrganisationContext";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <OrganisationProvider>
      <OrganisationContext.Consumer>
        {({ organisations }) =>
          organisations ? (
            organisations.map(organisation => {
              return <li key={organisation.id}>{organisation.name}</li>;
            })
          ) : (
            <div>loading</div>
          )
        }
      </OrganisationContext.Consumer>
    </OrganisationProvider>
  );
}
```

And the updated `useEffect` in `OrganisationsContext.tsx`:

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setOrganisations([
      { id: "1", name: "google" },
      { id: "2", name: "stackoverflow" }
    ]);
  }, []);
```

Comment: This problem was consuming me for a while, thanks for your swift and detailed response!